# Getting System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit in windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

From where i will get "System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit" for windows phone 7. From a blog i read that by using this library i can leverage many existing characters of silverlight. Especially Transitioning content control. I tried this assebly in tool kit and in MS website but desn't find any result. If any one tried the same, pls share ur knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the [Silverlight Toolkit on CodePlex](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) , or [on NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SilverlightToolkitWP)

It support easier transition effects. Try the sample application and see for yourself.

Comment: I am  aware about silverlight toolkit. But that was not my question , i need “System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit” library.. If it is available in WP7

Comment: So you want something that don't exist? Right, have fun with that then.

Comment: How come you can say it is not present? Take a luk on this blog(http://www.slickthought.net/post/2010/04/26/Simplifying-Page-Transitions-in-Windows-Phone-7-Silverlight-Applications.aspx). In that blog he is mentioned about the same dll. And also i found many questions in WP Forum about the same. I need to know does the dll is a customised one or a productive one from MS. The question is all about gaining knowledge not for harassing any one.

Comment: i confused only beacouse of the name of the DLL.